# При выгрузке данных с БД через psycopg2 и дальнейшей записи через Openpyxl в лист эксель, функции экселя отказываются воспринимать один из рядов

Tags: python, postgresql, excel, openpyxl, psycopg2

Выгружаю с БД postgres данные через psycopg2.
В скрипте SQL есть такой фрагмент

```
case when name_column is true then 'ИСТИНА' else 'ЛОЖЬ' end  as name_column
```

После выгрузки происходит копирование и запись этих данных через openpyxl в эксель листы.
Запись выглядит примерно вот так.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На других листах происходит вычисления данных из этой простыни.
Проблема состоит в том что функции эксель отказываются видеть последний столб с данными "ЛОЖЬ" или "ИСТИНА"
Пример формулы

```
=СЧЁТЕСЛИМН(Data1!$A:$A;ATB$3;Data1!$H:$H;ЛОЖЬ)
```

И формула ничего не просчитывает и выводит нули.
Если удалить значение "ЛОЖЬ" в одной из ячеек и написать там же только вручную, формула начинает считать эту ячейку.
Тип данных одинаковый в ячейках.
При выгрузке с DataGrip и вставке вручную все работает нормально.
Желательно решить проблему так, что бы не изменять sql скрипт и эксель файл.
Возможно проблема с кодировкой в UTF-8? Если да, то куда и как пристроить кусок кода который будет декодировать/перекодировать..?

Но, так же есть формулы которые ссылаются на другие столбцы с кириллицей, и при этом работают нормально. Возможно проблема в том что эксель не понимает что это булевые значения? Если так, как это исправить?
Код

```
import psycopg2
from contextlib import closing
from psycopg2.extras import DictCursor
import pandas as pd
from tkcalendar import Calendar,DateEntry
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
import os
from ... import sheets
import time
 
def write_to_excel(name_file):

    
    
    with psycopg2.connect(dbname='', 
                                     user="", 
                                     password="", 
                                     host='', 
                                     port ='') as connection:
        with connection.cursor(cursor_factory=DictCursor) as cursor:

            for name_sheet in sheets:
                print(f'Запускаю скрипт {name_sheet}')
                cursor.execute(sheets[name_sheet]) 
                rows = [[desc[0] for desc in cursor.description]]
                for row in cursor: 
                    rows.append(row)
                print(f'Выгрузили и скопировали {name_sheet}')

    
                clear_wb = load_workbook(name_file) 
                excel_sheet = clear_wb[name_sheet]
                excel_sheet.delete_rows(1,excel_sheet.max_row + 1)
                
                data = rows 
                print(len(rows))
                print(len(rows[0]))

                
          
                for i in data: 
                               
                     excel_sheet.append(i)

                clear_wb.save(name_file)
                print(f'Сохранили {name_sheet}')
            clear_wb.close()

start_time = time.time()
write_to_excel('file.xlsx')
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: Скорей всего проблемы с форматом данных в ячейке. Попробуйте записать на новый лист, который не очищали, заработает ли формула?

Comment: Не работает, формат ячеек не меняется, везде стоит "общий". Пока что проблему решил тем что все таки изменил с ИСТИНА ЛОЖЬ на 1 и 0 в sql и exel соответственно. Впринципе это всех устроило, но все равно интересно узнать причину)